# What is the method to execute PHP array one by one after insert into db for all arrays?

Tags: php, foreach, controls, associative-array, operation

```
$countsara= array(array("a"=>"hello","b"=>"how","c"=>"are","d"=>"you","e"=>"david"),                    array("a"=>"hello","b"=>"how","c"=>"are","d"=>"you","e"=>"kaser"),array("a"=>"hello","b"=>"how","c"=>"are","d"=>"you","e"=>"albert"),array("a"=>"hello","b"=>"how","c"=>"are","d"=>"you","e"=>"stephen"));

    foreach ($countsara as $tommykey=>$tommyval) {
     foreach ($tommyval as $tommyvalkey=>$tommyvalval) {
      echo $tommyvalkey.' - '.$tommyvalval;
      echo '<br>';
      echo 'test';
      }
     }
```

For example, there are 100 arrays. I want to get the first array values and insert into db, then 2nd and then until 100th array values.

I can able to insert the value into db but the issue is, if there are 100 arrays. The foreach is executing for 100 times. So the insert is happening for 100 times for a same id on a same record row. Which is a re-insert not a duplicate.

If there are totally 100 arrays in `$tommyval`. As usual, the test is being executed for 10 times. I am going to do an operation in the place of `echo test;` So I don't want to repeat the same operation 100 times.

**How to avoid this in PHP foreach array repetition at the same time I want all the array to be executed?**

Comment: Sorry but it's too hard to understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: Is there any other way that we can get the values from an associative array at the same time can insert into db each array one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$countsara= array(array("a"=>"hello","b"=>"how","c"=>"are","d"=>"you","e"=>"david"),                    array("a"=>"hello","b"=>"how","c"=>"are","d"=>"you","e"=>"kaser"),array("a"=>"hello","b"=>"how","c"=>"are","d"=>"you","e"=>"albert"),array("a"=>"hello","b"=>"how","c"=>"are","d"=>"you","e"=>"stephen"));

    foreach ($countsara as $tommykey=>$tommyval) {
     foreach ($tommyval as $tommyvalkey=>$tommyvalval) {
      echo $tommyvalkey.' - '.$tommyvalval;
      echo '<br>';
      }
      echo 'test';
     }
```

The change that I made was placed the `echo 'test';` after the completion of second foreach. I got what I wanted. I executed only once and so as the insertion into db also happens only once.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean that you want to execute the insert portion of the code 10 times but //echo 'test'; portion should only be executed once, try setting a flag which will only let the //echo part once and stop it from executing with every loop

Comment: Even the flag block of code is executed repeatedly for 100 times.

Comment: @BannedfromSO Not if you use it properly, show some code with flag.

Comment: `foreach ($countsara as $tommykey=>$tommyval) {
  foreach ($tommyval as $tommyvalkey=>$tommyvalval) {
   $arrayinsertflag = 1;
   echo 'test'; 
   if($arrayinsertflag == 1) {
    echo $tommyvalval.'Only once<br>';
    // I wanted all array values to be printed here only once...
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: set the flag as true outside the loop. and do something like this if (flag) {echo;flag=false;}

Comment: if you want all the array values to be printed here only once, do not write the echo  in the loop, instead push the values into an another array and then print it once after the loop ends
u can also add $arrayinsertflag=0 right after echo $tommyvalval

Comment: No it isn't working. Still it executes because any ways it's inside a foreach. What I wanted is? if there are 5 arrays, after execution of 1 array all the value of 1st array should be inserted into db. Then 2nd execution for 2nd array, insert the values into db and so on.

Comment: you have to implement a logic that does that. show me your code about how you are trying to do that and I will try to hepl u